# Error in RSS Report

Tags: xml, rss

I have an Error in the Rss Report using Ajax :

I use the config.inc.php functions.inc.php for the database. Even i given permissions to the Files and Folder.

But I am not receiving the data from the .xml file.

Please anyone help me. 
How can i receive the data from the .xml file ?

Here is my Code :

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once('includes/config.inc.php');
require_once('includes/functions.inc.php');

$configpath = "surveys/config_" . $_REQUEST['sid'] . ".php";    
include_once($configpath); // load survey settings

$rss_template = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>
<rss version=\"2.0\">
<channel>
    <title>AskPeople Survey Responses</title>
    <description>Live project status (requires login to view results)</description>
    <link>[[PROJ-LINK]]</link>
    <language>en-gb</language>
    <pubDate>[[NOW]]</pubDate>
    <lastBuildDate>[[NOW]]</lastBuildDate>
    <generator>AskPeople 2.2</generator>
    <item>
        <title>[[TITLE]]</title>
        <description>[[COUNT]] responses received as of [[NOW]].</description>
        <link>[[ITEM-LINK]]</link>
    </item>
</channel>
</rss>";

if ($_REQUEST['sid']) {
    $_SESSION['admin_sid'] = $_REQUEST['sid'];
}

if ($surveysettings['makeRSS'] == "TRUE") {

    $now = date("r");

    $directory = (substr(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']),-1) == "/") ? dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) : dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . "/";
    $projlink = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $directory . "survey.php?sid=".$_SESSION['admin_sid'];
    $reportlink = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $directory . "respondentreport.php?sid=".$_SESSION['admin_sid'];

    $datafile = "surveys/data_" . $_SESSION['admin_sid'] . ".dat";
    $rawdata = loadFile($datafile);
    $rawdata_array = explode("\n",$rawdata);
    $counter = 0;
    for ($r=0;$r<count($rawdata_array);$r++) {
        if (strlen($rawdata_array[$r])>0 && $rawdata_array[$r] != "Array") { // some data for this row
            $counter++;
        }
    }

    $qid = "surveys/quest_" . $_SESSION['admin_sid'] . ".xml";
    $polldata = file_get_contents($qid);
    preg_match_all("/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/si",$polldata,$title);
    $title = $title[1][0] . ": ". $counter . " responses";

    $rss_template = str_replace("[[PROJ-LINK]]",$projlink,$rss_template);
    $rss_template = str_replace("[[ITEM-LINK]]",$reportlink,$rss_template);
    $rss_template = str_replace("[[NOW]]",$now,$rss_template);
    $rss_template = str_replace("[[TITLE]]",$title,$rss_template);
    $rss_template = str_replace("[[COUNT]]",$counter,$rss_template);

if ($_REQUEST['file'] == "TRUE") { // for output to a static file
        $saved = saveFile($rss_filename,$rss_template);
    } else {
        echo ($rss_template);
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Where do you get the request from your ajax ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your if Condition to the Request :

```
if ($_REQUEST['file'] == "TRUE") { // for output to a static file
        $rss_filename = "rss/rss_".$_SESSION['admin_sid'] . ".xml";
        $saved = saveFile($rss_filename,$rss_template);
    } else {
        echo ($rss_template);
    }
```